# Why can't I create a callback for the List Find method in Moq?

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, delegates, entity-framework-6, moq

I created an extension method that lets me treat a List as DbSet for testing purposes (actually, I found this idea in another question here on stack overflow, and it's been fairly useful).  Coded as follows:

```
    public static DbSet<T> AsDbSet<T>(this List<T> sourceList) where T : class
    {
        var queryable = sourceList.AsQueryable();

        var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
        mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
        mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
        mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
        mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(queryable.GetEnumerator());
        mockDbSet.Setup(d => d.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>(sourceList.Add);
        mockDbSet.Setup(d => d.Find(It.IsAny<object[]>())).Callback(sourceList.Find);
        return mockDbSet.Object;
    }
```

I had been using Add for awhile, and that works perfectly.  However, when I try to add the callback for Find, I get a compiler error saying that it can't convert a method group to an action.  Why is sourceList.Add an Action, but sourceList.Find is a method group?

I'll admit I'm not particularly familiar with C# delegates, so it's likely I'm missing something very obvious.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `Add` works is because the `List<T>.Add` method group contains a single method which takes a single argument of type `T` and returns void. This method has the same signature as an `Action<T>` which is one of the overloads of the `Callback` method (the one with a single generic type parameter, `Callback<T>`), therefore the `List<T>.Add` method group can be converted to an `Action<T>`.

With `Find`, you are trying to call the `Callback` method (as opposed to `Callback<T>`) which expects an `Action` parameter (as opposed to `Action<T>`). The difference here is that an `Action` does not take any parameters, but an `Action<T>` takes a single parameter of type T. The `List<T>.Find` method group cannot be converted to an `Action` because all the `Find` methods (there is only one anyway) take input parameters.

The following will compile:

```
    public static DbSet<T> AsDbSet<T>(this List<T> sourceList) where T : class
    {
        var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
        mockDbSet.Setup(d => d.Find(It.IsAny<object[]>())).Callback<Predicate<T>>(t => sourceList.Find(t));
        return mockDbSet.Object;
    }
```

Note that I have called `.Callback<Predicate<T>>` because the `List<T>.Find` method expects and argument of type Predicate. Also note I have had to write `t => sourceList.Find(t)` instead of `sourceList.Find` because `Find` returns a value (which means it doesn't match the signature of `Action<Predicate<T>>`). By writing it as a lambda expression the return value will be thrown away.

Note that although this compiles it will not actually work because the `DbSet.Find` method actually takes an `object[]` for it's parameter, not a `Predicate<T>`, so you will likely have to do something like this:

```
    public static DbSet<T> AsDbSet<T>(this List<T> sourceList) where T : class
    {
        var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
        mockDbSet.Setup(d => d.Find(It.IsAny<object[]>())).Callback<object[]>(keyValues => sourceList.Find(keyValues.Contains));
        return mockDbSet.Object;
    }
```

This last point has more to do with how to use the Moq library that how to use method groups, delegates and lambdas - there is all sorts of syntactic sugar going on with this line which is hiding what is actually relevant to the compiler and what isn't.

Comment: Thank you! I've been beating my head against this for several hours, and your explanation is very informative.

Comment: No problem. I should add that in the second half of my answer I got lazy and stopped distinguishing between methods and method groups. If you ever get stuck on this subject again, I highly recommend the book "C# in depth" by Jon Skeet. It explains more exactly how the conversion processes work between method groups, lambdas and delegates.

Comment: So in order to actually get the value from the Callback method when I invoke Find on the mock, I guess I have to do something like this: `mockDbSet.Setup(d => d.Find(It.IsAny<object[]>())).Callback<object[]>(k => item = sourceList.Find(k.Contains)).Returns(() => item);`  I will take a look at the book next time I get a chance.

Comment: Nearly - use `Returns` *instead* of `Callback` (don't chain both together), and you will get the value back. e.g. `mockDbSet.Setup(d => d.Find(It.IsAny<object[]>())).Returns<object[]>(keyValues => sourceList.Find(keyValues.Contains));`